# Horizontal RecyclerView always scrolls to last item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`, which is set `horizontal` and loaded with a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. On all items I set `OnClickListeners`. The problem is, the RecyclerView always scrolls to the last item. So instead of showing the first item, I see the last one. When I don't set a OnClickListener, the RecyclerView works as it should and doesn't scroll to the last item.

I have already tried `setFocusable(false)` and `scrollToPosition(0)`

My code:

In order to use a `load more button` I override methods in the Adapter to use more than one layout, since the FirebaseAdapter doesn't load items inside a HorizontalScrollView, but I think this shouldn't be the problem.

```
mStoriesAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.list_item_outputdetail_story, PostHolder.class, query) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PostHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {

            if (model != null) {

                viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StoryActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.PASS_POST_TO_STORY_ACTIVITY, model);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.STORY_ACTIVITY_TYPE, Constants.STORY_ACTIVITY_ONE_STORY);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.FIREBASE_KEY, firebaseKey);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.name.setText(model.getUser().getUserName());
                viewHolder.heartsNumber.setText(String.valueOf(model.getNumLikes()));
                viewHolder.title.setText(model.getTitleText());
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(model.getTimeCreated());
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                viewHolder.date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.getUser().getPictureUri()).into(viewHolder.profilPicture);

                FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference imageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child(model.getPostId());
                GlideApp.with(getActivity()).load(imageReference).into(viewHolder.imageView);

                FirebaseUtils.checkForAlreadyLiked(model.getPostId(), viewHolder.hearts, firebaseKey);

            } else if (position == 0) {

                viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WriteStoryActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.FIREBASE_KEY, firebaseKey);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            } else {

                viewHolder.showAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StoryActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.STORY_ACTIVITY_TYPE, Constants.STORY_ACTIVITY_ALL_STORIES);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.FIREBASE_KEY, firebaseKey);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public Post getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return null;
            } else if (super.getItemCount() < 5 || position < getItemCount() - 2) {
                return super.getItem(position - 1);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if (super.getItemCount() < 5) {
                return super.getItemCount() + 1;
            } else {
                return super.getItemCount() + 2;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (super.getItemCount() < 5) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return R.layout.list_item_outputdetail_story_write_your_own;
                } else {
                    return super.getItemViewType(position);
                }
            } else {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return R.layout.list_item_outputdetail_story_write_your_own;
                } else if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
                    return R.layout.list_item_outputdetail_story_showall_fab;
                } else  {
                    return super.getItemViewType(position);
                }
            }
        }

    };
    LinearLayoutManager storiesManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mStoriesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(storiesManager);
    mStoriesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mStoriesAdapter);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Too anyone who still needs this. The answer is just that you cannot set an `OnClickListener` in an `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

The best idea is to do a workaround like in this post. [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)